# XPath - "get first tr where its first td has text equal to 'abcd'"

Tags: xpath

I currently have the following xpath: `//tr[td//text()='AD'][1]`

From my understanding, this means: `"find the first tr which has some td child which  has any descendant whose text is equal to 'AD'"`

Is this correct? If so, I would like to change the xpath to the following definition:

`"find the first tr whose second td child has text equal to 'AD'"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "find the first tr whose second td child has text equal to 'AD'"

might be implemented as

```
//tr[td[position()=2 and text()="AD"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of `//tr[td//text()='AD'][1]` is not quite as you say. It expands to `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::tr[child::td//text()='AD'][1]`, which means "for each descendant node, return the first child `tr` element that has a descendant text node equal to 'AD'.

You should instead write `(//tr[td//text()='AD'])[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do
`//td[contains(text(), 'AD']/parent::node()` as well